# HTTPError: 400 client Error: user 'x' has no verified email addresses while pushing python package to pypi

Tags: package, pypi, uploading

HTTPError: 400 Client Error: User 'sampleuser' has no verified email addresse
s, please verify at least one address before registering a new project on PyPI.
See https://pypi.org/help/#verified-email for more information. for url: https:/
/upload.pypi.org/legacy/

The above error I am getting when I run " twine upload dist/* " command

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alright, I figured out:

You need to login to https://pypi.org/ instead of the old https://pypi.python.org/pypi.

https://pypi.org shows a "pre-production" warning on top, but that doesn't matter. Login to your account, go to account setting, and verify your email. The old site doesn't have a way to check whether your email is verified or not.

Comment: @Parousia please try this

Comment: Thanks @Ainz. I'll try it when I get home. On mobile right now. Really it said something about verification of account but I couldn't find any such thing on the site.

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing the same problem right now while trying to update a repo that's already on PyPi.

But I found this [link](https://status.python.org/incidents/twsl95ccmg52) on my profile page and on clicking it I read

> we are experiencing issues with pypi.org and the upload.pypi.org
>   endpoint. we're actively working to resolve the issue and will update
>   here as we're able.

Comment: even though they say it's resolved, it still doesn't work for me when I want to register new project